# Merge 2 Lists of different types using LinQ

Tags: c#, string, linq, list, int

I have 2 lists. If both of them are of type `string`. I can merge them by using something like:

```
List<string> myCars = new List<String> { "Yugo", "Aztec", "BMW" };
List<string> modeList = new List<String> { "BMW", "Saab", "Aztec" };
var carConcat = (from c in myCars select c)
.Concat(from c2 in modeList select c2);
```

However, how can I obtain (*quickly*) the similar results if I have one `List<string>`, one `List<int>`

```
List<string> myCars = new List<String> { "Yugo", "Aztec", "BMW" };
List<int> modeList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `List` is expecting strongly-typed data type, thus one of the data type must give in. And in between `string` and `int`, `int` can always be represented as `string` but not all `string` can be represented as `int` (only numeric type under certain range). Thus, `int` data type *should* give in.

Then you could use `ToString()` to change the `int` data type to `string` and combine it with your original `List`.

```
List<string> myCars = new List<String> { "Yugo", "Aztec", "BMW" };
List<int> modeList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var carConcat = myCars.Concat(from c2 in modeList select c2.ToString());
```

Alternatively, you could create `List<object>` which encompass all the data types.

**Edit:**

Note that you could also remove the identity select `(from c in myCars select c)`, credited to [Aron's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759593/merge-2-lists-of-different-types-using-linq/36759612?noredirect=1#comment61099060_36759612).

Comment: Thanks. Simple and effective

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen I would give a check my answer. This answer is correct, but I believe that you don't need to convert to string everything and also, I don't think that using a LINQ statement in your case should be the best solution.

Comment: What is the `from c in XXX select c` doing? Isn't that just the identity monad?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you should note that `Enumerable.Concat` is an extension method to `IEnumerable<T>` and `List<T>` implements this interface. Thus, you don't need to use LINQ syntax for this:

```
// When both lists are of string...
IEnumerable<string> all = myCars.Concat(modeList);
```

In the other hand, if you want to mix both lists but one of them has a different generic type, then, you can still mix them casting all items to `object`:

```
IEnumerable<object> all = myCars.Cast<object>().Concat(modeList.Cast<object>());
```

...or since `IEnumerable<T>` is [*covariant*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<object> all = ((IEnumerable<object>)myCars).Concat(modeList.Cast<object>());
```

The main drawback of above solution is that there're few corner cases where you'll want to store your references as `object`, since you're forcing your code to later downcast them again to the actual type if you want to access their members (i.e. methods, properties...).

Comment: Upvoted (this answer is useful) for the explanation.