# Merge two lists with objects into third list

Tags: c#, list, merge

'I have two lists with different objects. I want to combine all of the data into object3. Id is the common field in all the objects'

'Object1 -> has ID, Name'

'Object2 -> has ID, Street, City'

'Object3-> has ID, Name, Street, City'

```
'''List<Customer> cust = new List<Customer>();
List<Order> order = new List<Order>();
List<OrderDetails> orderDetails = new List<OrderDetails>();

Customer obj = new Customer();
obj.ID = 5; obj.Name = "Sam"; cust.Add(obj);

Customer obj1 = new Customer();
obj.ID = 6; obj.Name = "Ram"; cust.Add(obj1);

Customer obj2 = new Customer();
obj.ID = 7; obj.Name = "Alex"; cust.Add(obj2);

Order order1 = new Order();
order1.ID = 5; order1.Product = "Book"; order.Add(order1);

Order order2 = new Order();
order2.ID = 6; order2.Product = "Game"; order.Add(order2);

Order order3 = new Order();
order3.ID = 8; order2.Product = "Computer"; order.Add(order3);

var od = from c in cust
         join o in order
         on c.ID equals o.ID
         select new OrderDetails
         {
             ID = c.ID,
             Name = c.Name,
             Product = o.Product
         };

orderDetails = od.ToList();'''
```

'orderDetails count is 0'

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579324/how-merge-two-lists-of-different-objects/24579534

Comment: If you have any problems getting this to work using _LINQ_ (hint `join` on the `ID` field), come back and ask a question. We don't just write your code for you

Comment: This one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759593/merge-2-lists-of-different-types-using-linq

Comment: The query is executing without error but resultant count is 0. I updated my question with additional details.

Answer (score 0):

- Initialize a list to hold items of type `Object3`
- Loop through the list which has items of type `Object1`
- While looping, based on the `ID`, find the match within the second list
- If it does not have a match, continue
- If it has a match, create an object of type `Object3` with information from the item being looped (`Object1`) and the match (`Object2`). Add it to the list which you created in first step.

You now have a list of `Object3` as per your requirement.

Now, it's just a matter of syntax and then adding some sugar if you like it that way.